# Java - create an instance of file reader and output

Tags: java, filereader, priority-queue

I have a program which reads some data under a file reader and then creates an instance of another class which models the data. Anyway that class works (has been tested with some hard coded values) but I now want to output the data of the instance of a Patient being read under the file reader but seem unable to.

Could anyone tell me where i'm going wrong.

Comment: Well the 1st problem is you exception handler is not printing out the exception.  You should call printStackTrace() to see the error.

Comment: I can actually print out the data directly but thus does not accomplish what i want with a priority queue and doesn't work, but works with some hard coded values so possibly my for loop thats the issue

Answer (score 1):

You are not adding Patient instances to `newPatient` collection, that's why it's empty and you are not getting anything printed out. Add elements to queue:

```
 while(scan.hasNextLine()){
            String firstname = scan.nextLine();
            String surname = scan.nextLine();
            String illness = scan.nextLine();
            int illnessSeverity = scan.nextInt();
            String newLine = scan.nextLine();

            newPatient.add(new Patient(firstname,surname,illness,illnessSeverity));

        for (Patient newPatientData : newPatient) {
            System.out.println(newPatientData);
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add data first to the Priority Queue. I think you missed that .

```
PriorityQueue<Patient> newPatient = new PriorityQueue<>();
    File fileName = new File("patients.txt");

    Scanner scan = null;

    try {
        scan = new Scanner(fileName);
        while(scan.hasNextLine()){
            String firstname = scan.nextLine();
            String surname = scan.nextLine();
            String illness = scan.nextLine();
            int illnessSeverity = scan.nextInt();
            String newLine = scan.nextLine();

            Patient newP = new Patient(firstname,surname,illness,illnessSeverity);
     newPatient.add(newP);
           }

        for (Patient newPatientData : newPatient) {

            System.out.println(newPatientData);
        }   


        } catch(Exception e) {
            System.out.println("ERROR - file not found");  
        }
```

Comment: Ah yes I see now, thanks! but going on the above code my priority queue doesn't work correctly. Any suggestions? but seem to work on hard coded data. see original message for this method

Comment: It is because you are not using the poll() method of the queue. The loop iterator does not return in  the sorted order .  Instead of for loop do this                                                       while(!newPatient.isEmpty())                                                                                {   System.out.println(newPatient.poll());}